# Optimize 2 mysql queries into one

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Using php and mysql 5.x. I currently load a banner image in a certain section of my site like so:

```
SELECT * FROM banners WHERE section = 1 AND pageid = 2
```

But if no results found I run a second query:

```
SELECT * FROM banners WHERE section = 1 AND pageid = 0
```

Basically what Im doing is trying to find banner images assigned to that section for that page. If no results found then I look for any default banner images in the second query. Is there a better way where I can do this in one query?

**EDIT**

To clarify a little bit more. I want to check if there is any banners assigned to the page, if not then see if there is any banners assigned to 0 (Default). I dont want a mix of both either it shows all banners assigned to that page or show all banners assigned to pageid 0 and there could be a possibility of multiple rows returned not just one.

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**

To better explain what this is for. In an admin tool I allow someone to assign a banner image to section on the website. In the admin tool they can select the section and the page they want the banner image to show. They can also set the default banner image(s) for that section. So if there were no banner images assigned to a section by default it will load the banner image(s) assigned to 0 for that section throughout the website. So instead of assigning a default banner image to 50 different pages they can just do it one time and it will load the default banner image or images for that section. Just trying to find a way to do this in a more optimal way, instead of 2 queries could it be done in one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the most elegant way, but you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM banners 
WHERE section = 1 
AND pageid = IF(
    (select count(*) from banners where section = 1 and pageid = 2) = 0, 
    0, 2
);
```

Comment: @Karolis Well I dont know about optimization but when I did an explain it looked good, no temp tables or full table scans. So I will use this. Thank you!

Comment: @John subselect does not have any dynamic values, so MySQL calculates the value of subselect before the main select is executed. So the speed should be almost the same as running 2 separate queries mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Karolis The good part is I can query a seperate table to get the count and that second table is a myisam so getting the count should be really fast.

Comment: @John Count on MyISAM is fast when there is no `where` clause in select statement. But I think it is still fast enough.

Comment: @Karolis Oh I thought myisam was faster getting the count(*) vs innodb even with a where clause.

Comment: @John It's quite possible that count(*) on MyISAM is faster than in innodb, but it still needs to do some calculations for to get the count. If there is no `where` clause in select statement then MySQL needs no any calculations for to get the count from MyISAM, you get the count immediately.

Answer (score 3):

The `OR` operator will make the conditional `(pageid = 2 OR pageid = 0)` return `true` immediately if just the first value is `true` and since there is a `LIMIT 1` I think it should always fetch one with `pageid = 2` first since the order of `pageid` is `DESC` and 2 is bigger than 0.

```
SELECT * FROM banners WHERE section = 1 AND (pageid = 2 OR pageid = 0) ORDER BY pageid DESC LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**: I'm not positive if the `ORDER BY` is necessary, I'd love to see some comments on that

Comment: It's not ok, because you can not guaranty which of 2 rows will be returned. You should add `order by` or something.

Comment: What about with the GROUP BY though?

Comment: @Connor In the case it's not important which value is the first against `OR`. The result order is still unexpected. You need to `order by pageid desc`

Comment: oops yeah I meant `order` not `group` I keep doing that on accident in my own code too >.<

Comment: @Connor Smith As I stated in the other answer on here this query does not work if I have multiple rows returned. It returns not only the banner images with the current page id but also the banner ids with pageid of zero. It cant be both, its either all banner images assigned to the page or all banner images assigned to zero. I cant have a mixture of both.

Comment: @John Have you tried it? It will not return multiple rows! See `LIMIT 1`

Comment: You can use ORDER BY FIELD to prioritize the banners from page_id 2 before those from page_id 0. In the case ORDER by page_id DESC will work as well, but in other cases ORDER BY FIELD() is the way to go.

Comment: @Connor Smith But it needs to be able to return multiple rows. I updated my original post. Sorry for the confusion. I ran the query without the limit clause and it gives me both rows assigned to the current pageid and banner images assigned to zero. It cant be both.